# Applescript IF Google Chrome is in fullscreen mode

Tags: google-chrome, applescript, kiosk-mode

I'm working with a kiosk (touch screen) and I want the script to sense if Chrome isn't running. And if it isn't running - Start Chrome in fullscreen mode.

The sample below works, except that if I quit Chrome it will start in full screen and the applescript will destroy the full screen mode.

Can AppleScript sense if Google Chrome is in fullscreen mode?

**Like: if application "Google Chrome" is in fullscreen mode then ...**

```
if application "Google Chrome" is not running then
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate
        tell application "System Events"
            delay 2
            keystroke "f" using {shift down, command down}
        end tell
    end tell
end if
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One hack is to check if the number of windows returned by System Events and the application are the same:

```
tell application "System Events" to number of windows of process "Google Chrome"
tell application "Google Chrome" to number of windows is not result
```

System Events does not include full screen windows but applications do.